# What kind of panniers is this tubus rack flange for?

Tags: rack, panniers

I was bolting on my Tubus Nova front rack and noticed that there were bolt holes on the bottom of it, and got to wondering what they are for.  The [instructions](http://www.tubus.com/documents/1329746055_Ergo_Nova.pdf) are mostly in pictures and just show that it is to attach this little flange "for panniers".  I'm mostly familiar with Ortlieb-style panniers that clip on the top and a sideways hook below.  What kind of pannier attachment would use this sort of thing?

[image: Extract from Tubus Nova Manual]

Comment: Many panniers have a hook at the bottom that needs to "grab" some sort of eyelet.  My TransIts have this -- a hook that is tightened by a web strap that runs in a V from one top corner, down through the hook, and to the other top corner, with a adjustable buckle to tighten the strap.  My old (and greatly missed) Cannondale bags had a spring running down with a loop on the bottom, and you needed to fasten a hook to the bottom of the rack frame to match.

Comment: Old Ortlieb bags have a rubber strap hooking into such an eye as well. Tubus and Ortlieb usually match very well, which may be a reason for Tubus to keep the eye.

Comment: The old Karrimor panniers had a hook on an elastic cord that fitted into an eye at the bottom of the pannier too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work with my pannier set. I have Axiom Monsoon panniers with a hook at the bottom that would fit right about there.